# Multiple Attributes Count

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, symbology, count

I have a set of x,y data used to plot transit pickups. I am using the multiple attributes function in the symbology tab to show how many different pickup locations the agency is traveling to. I'm using latitude and longitude coordinates for my multiple attributes.

[image]

I then want to be able to make the size of the symbol dependent on the count. Is there a way to do this within ArcGIS 10.3.1? Right now pickup points that are the same just show up on top of each other.

When I go to the symbol size button, I'm only able to use latitude or longitude for symbol size which is not what I am wanting.

I'd like to be able to show the more frequented locations.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your attribute table ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include a bit more detail about your data, including a screenshot, to give potential answerers a clearer picture of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to my the size of the symbol dependent on the count.

I used a shapefile depicting City locations in the US. The shapefiles attribute table has a field call POP_Class that has provided values from 5-10 for each city.

For your file you can follow the same steps in ArcGIS 10.3.1 to arrive to the same results.

Have you shapefile ready:

[image]

Then go to table of contents and right-click your shapefile and choose properties.

[image]

Then go to the symbology tab and choose multiple attributes and input your field of interest.

[image]

Click on symbol size, enter field and modify as needed.

[image]

Now your data is visualized proportional to it's attribute

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that does not help in my case. I have two fields in the multiple attribute field. I have latitude and longitude as my two fields. So I can't change the symbol size because it will only select latitude or longitude. I want the symbols to size based on the count in the right hand column.